# elasticsearch update by query retries

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

does [update by query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) has `retry_on_conflict` like `update api`?

I see the response has

```
"retries": {
  "bulk": 0,
  "search": 0
}
```

but I can't see where it says we can retry. It only says you can choose to `proceed` or `abort` on conflict.

Comment: The logic is explained [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/14829) but there is currently no exposed parameter to control this.